# Understanding Mathematica's InverseZTransform Function

Tags: integral-transforms

I'm trying to find the Inverse Z Transform of the following:

```
InverseZTransform[(1 - ρ)/(1 - ρ z), z, n]
```

and I get from *Mathematica* the result

```
- (1 - ρ) ρ^-n UnitStep[n - 1].
```

But, I know the result should be:

```
  (1 - ρ) ρ^n
```

I don't understand *Mathematica*'s result - Why $\rho^{-n}\,θ(n-1)$?

Here is an example from page 65 of [this document](http://www.win.tue.nl/~iadan/queueing.pdf):

[image]

Comment: Did you check that the definition you are accustomed to matches that of *Mathematica*'s?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question...

Comment: You meant to say that the out put should be `(-1 + rho) (rho^-n) `?

Comment: "I know the result should be..." - what do you get if you run `ZTransform[(1 - ρ) ρ^n, n, z]`?

Comment: It seems correct. One recovers the function as `Sum[-(1 - ρ) ρ^-n*z^(-n), {n, 1, ∞}]`.

Comment: Can you link to the reference you got this excerpt from, please?

Comment: Sure - Here is the link - Page 65 - http://www.win.tue.nl/~iadan/queueing.pdf

Comment: Next time, please edit your post when including references, instead of leaving it in a comment.

Comment: @J.M. It seems to me that this is not a MMA issue. Check page 3 http://www.win.tue.nl/~iadan/que/h4.pdf

Comment: When you $ZTransform[-(1 - \rho) \rho^{-n}\ \ UnitStep[-1 + n], n, z]$ and then evaluate deriviative at $z=1$, then you DO get the correct answer - I.e., $\rho/(1-\rho)$ - So (I believe) the answer Mathematica gives is correct (not that it's in doubt), but It's in a strange format...IMO

Comment: @MMM, then `GeneratingFunction[]`/`SeriesCoefficient[]` seems to be the appropriate functions, and not `ZTransform[]`/`InverseZTransform[]`.

Comment: @J.M. OP probably wanted to use short cut to get the answer. Otherwise, It just require a little algebraic manipulation.

Comment: Ok - I've never heard/used that function before...